# How to run a script file from ipython

Tags: ipython

How do you run a script from iPython?

I am looking for a way to stop quitting and opening iPython each time I made a change to the classes I'm working on. reload is not working well for me.

The contents of the script `./hello-world.py` I'm trying to run from iPython is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print('hello world')
```

I've tried

```
hello-world.py                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-136f991ec00e> in <module>
----> 1 remap-discourse-users-to-wordpress.py

NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

and

```
 ./hello-world.py                                                                                                                              
  File "<ipython-input-7-6d10642b89fe>", line 1
    ./remap-discourse-users-to-wordpress.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Provide an [MCVE] in your question

Comment: Not sure how I could do that in this instance ... the script exists. I'll add that.

Comment: Replace your complex `remap-discourse-users-to-worldpress.py` script by something perhaps as simpls as `hello-world.py` script

Comment: To run a program (perhaps another Python script) from Python, consider [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: I was looking for a way to stop quitting and opening iPython each time I made a change to the classes I'm working on. reload not was working well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered all you have to add is `run`.

```
In [8]: run ./hello-world.py                                                                                                                          
hello-world
```

this has increased my productivity by being able to reload the models I'm working without having to rerun all the intervening steps to get back to the state I was at.